# VirtualBox shared folders, how to automount with commandline

Tags: linux, command-line, virtualbox

any ideas on subject? it seems that only Virtualbox manager do rihtfully connect of shared folders but that is not the case for commandline vm launch in linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but you should be able to edit */etc/fstab* to automount the shared folders.
For example if you have a folder named Shared.

If you add the following line to your */etc/fstab* of the guest machine:

**Shared /media/Shared vboxsf defaults 0 0**

this should do what you want.